# Why images are not showing up in iframe?

Tags: php, html, iframe, server

I am using iframe to show data from our media manager site. But iframe is not showing up images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>MM Test IFrame</title>
</head>
<body>
     <iframe width="100%" height="400" src="http://mediamanager.b- 
     yy.com/filemanager/newmediamanager/filemanager/dialog.php" 
      frameborder="0" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow- 
       y: scroll; "></iframe>
     </body>
  </html>
```

But if we directly try url then all is fine.
url: http://mediamanager.b- 
         yy.com/filemanager/newmediamanager/filemanager/dialog.php

Comment: may i have a look at the code at the php file

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Images show up when I test it (after removing the whitespace from the middle of the URL).

Comment: I think there is no issue with php code. Please have a look into image source. It's using relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though your link is broken.

```
http://mediamanager.b- yy.com/filemanager/newmediamanager/filemanager/dialog.php
                      ^
                     Here
```

Try removing that gap between ".b-" and ".yy.com".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>MM Test IFrame</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <iframe width="100%" height="400" src="http://mediamanager.b-yy.com/filemanager/newmediamanager/filemanager/dialog.php" 
             frameborder="0" style="overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; "></iframe>
        </body>
</html>
```

I tidied up your code a bit and fixed the link, just be careful about where you decide to line break in your code.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Even copying and pasting the code I provided works fine for me, what issue are you having?

Comment: Please check screen shot : http://prntscr.com/mrc42l

Comment: Thanks haha, not good enough though, apparently.